# how can i resolving this error in executing test.py?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

```
**usage: test.py [-h] --model_path MODEL_PATH [--testsize TESTSIZE]
           [--test_datasets TEST_DATASETS [TEST_DATASETS ...]]
           [--data_path DATA_PATH] [--save_path SAVE_PATH] [--multi_load]
```

test.py: error: the following arguments are required: --model_path
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2**

Comment: How are you executing it? From the `usage` it seems you are not passing `--model_path` which is a required argument for `test.py`

Comment: i fixed it, thanks